# Crontab throwing error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have the following content in crontab:

```
20 1,7,13,18 * * * /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup
15 * * * * root find /opt/activeMq/activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB/ -mtime +10 -type f -delete
```

but I get this when I restart cron service:

```
Feb 20 08:43:27 . crontab[14584]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Feb 20 08:44:08 . crontab[14584]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Feb 20 08:44:08 . crontab[14584]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Feb 20 08:44:28 . kernel: [325740.483115] init: cron main process (14563) killed by TERM signal
Feb 20 08:44:28 . cron[14641]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Feb 20 08:44:28 . cron[14642]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Feb 20 08:44:28 . cron[14642]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab
Feb 20 08:44:28 . cron[14642]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
Feb 20 08:44:28 . cron[14642]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
```

Comment: There is no `root` as sixth field in the first line. Is that ok? Try replacing with  `20 1,7,13,18 * * * root /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup`.

Comment: I did but getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Username field is only available at system level cron(etc/crontab) and not user level cron.